# Getting 405 Method Not Allowed on Postman

Tags: methods, postman, swagger

I am new in Postman and I was trying to implement Postman into my project. I am sure about using right method but still getting 405 Method Not Allowed. I know that its true because I am getting method from the Swagger page of the project.

[image]

[image]

And also I’ve imported Swagger into Postman but still the same.
Can you help me about what is wrong with it?

I am using same method that shown in Swagger but I still get that 405 error.

Comment: The values enclosed within the  double curly braces are env values, eg:   {{sample_env}}
you either have to supply the values through env or  you have to replace env  with your own values example : http://localhost:9000/yourpath , here i have replaced the baseurl with the local host url http://localhost:9000